# Cocoa: Implementing the target-action pattern in Objective-C and receiving 'NSInvalidArgumentException unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa-design-patterns

I'm attempting to implement the target-action pattern in a custom `UIControl`. Here's the setup:

```
// Inside custom UIControl class

- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    ...

    // UIControl method to update targets when values change
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    return YES;
}

- (void)valueChanged:(id)control
{
    NSLog(@"Value changed");
}
```

I have a simple view controller that initializes an instance of my custom UIControl and registers as a target for when values change:

```
// Inside view controller

@implementation HKViewController
{
    HKCustomControl *_customControl;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _customControl = [[HKCustomControl alloc]];

    [self.view addSubview:_customControl];

    [_customControl addTarget:self
                action:@selector(valueChanged:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

The error I get is: ''NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HKViewController valueChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d95b20'

I have added `- (void)valueChange:(id)control` to the `.h` file for my custom control as well.

I have read a number of posts already about similar errors but none specific to this pattern. I could use a second pair of eyes to see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `valueChanged:` needs to be in the view controller class, not the control class.

Answer (score 0):

`action` is sent to object specified in `addTarget` which is `self` as per your following statement:

```
[_customControl addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

So you need to add the `valueChanged` to controller class object.

Comment: Why would you do this? This means the control responds to its own changes. The need is for the view controller to know about the changes.

Comment: @maddy idea was to emphasize on the fact the `valueChanged:` should be defined in the class specified in `addTarget`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was provided by @rmaddy: I needed to have the `valueChanged:` method in the view controller instead of the class